# Unable to start ubuntu after install Nvidia-driver DKMS failed

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, docker

It says: `A start job is running for docker application container engine`.
After I switch to tty interface, it prompt the error that:

```
INFO: task systems-journal:348 blocked for more than 120 seconds.   
   Tainted: P OE 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu.
```

`echo o> /proc/says/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs` disables this message.

It seems to be Nvidia-docker failed to install.

Comment: Thanks, I've figured out the problem.   It may caused by incompletely installed nvidia driver.  Maybe I could try this at next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after remove and reinstall the nvidia driver, using `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
And make sure you have solved nvidia dependencies.